# Basement humidity 80-90% with unsealed concrete foundation, how can wood moisture be OK?

Tags: basement, moisture, humidity, dehumidifier

In summer our home in west Massachusetts has a humidity level of 80--90% for months, which according to what I read can be a serious problem. However, my [pinless moisture meter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07SZX8QXH) measures the wood beams at only 7-9%. How can this be: why moisture in wood doesn't reach equilibrium with air humidity? See [page 82 of this document](https://www.fpl.fs.fed.us/documnts/fplgtr/fpl_gtr190.pdf).

Last summer I ran a dehumidifier 24/7 (huge electricity bills) and only managed to make 3-5% difference. I concluded that the porous concrete foundation makes the dehumidifier essentially drawing the soil humidity from outside (concrete moisture is off the scale). It seems pointless to run dehumidifier in this case -- how do people deal with unsealed concrete foundation then? With my humidity & wood moisture levels, is there any cause for concern?

Comment: It could be the wood beam has a sealer on/in it or has been treated. The moisture may not cause much problem in the open areas where air circulation is possible. It usually causes problems in hidden areas where the airflow is restricted. In a stretch of humid days, put your hand on the wood beam, you might feel damp then.

Comment: This is excerpted from the document you linked "ounding air, which induce changes in wood moisture 
content. **These changes usually are gradual, and short-term fluctuations tend to influence only the wood surface. Moisture content changes can be retarded, but not prevented, by protective coatings such as varnish, lacquer, or paint**"

Comment: @r13 Yes, but the high humidity stays for all the summer months, probably from June to September. It doesn't look like that the wood has been treated, at least not the "finishing" types. Any treatment commonly used for basement beams & joists? I can look up pictures once I know what to search for.

Comment: There are a lot of factors that need to be considered, and nobody but you know what influential factors are present in your basement. If you have the patience to read that article, you shall be able to do your own calculation after all.